# PHP 8.1 Session variables disappear after redirection with header("location"

Tags: php, session, header, simplesamlphp

After a login page, we can see the contents of the `$_SESSION` array, but right after the header instruction, the variable `$_SESSION` disappear.

We have a multi-way for sign-in in our application, (one using username/password) that works fine, the other one using simplesaml 1.19 for SSO purposes that does not work

After the simplesaml access, we have a good result, (token looks fine) and the simplesaml session is cleaned

```
require_once('simplesaml/lib/_autoload.php');
$aSource = new \SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple('XXX');
$aSource->requireAuth();
$attributes = $aSource->getAttributes();
$sess_saml = SimpleSAML_Session::getSessionFromRequest();
$sess_saml->cleanup();
unset($aSource);
```

then the `$_SESSION` is created with good values, then it redirect to the main.php page, and the `$_SESSION` (is completely wipe, empty, so the user cannot login) and it loops back to the login page (which has a good SAML token and then reloop).

This code was working nicely with PHP 7.4 and Simplesaml 1.15

We see there is a new `session.cookie_samesite` in PHP8.1, We've tried all variations (LAX, None, Strict) but still not a valid `$_SESSION` after the script

```
header('location:main.php');
exit;
```

before the header command we have a complete `$_SESSION` variable (and proper values in the array), but after first instruction in "main.php" which is `session_start()` and the `$_SESSION` is then empty

We've been able to point that the `$_SESSION` is cleared by the redirect (so we do not think that simplesaml is involved) but the session management (when there is more than one type of `$_SESSION` within the call, that we do not understand). Is it an environment issue? Our environment is Windows Server 2022, IIS-10, PHP8.1, MySQL8

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found that all variations of the session.cookie_samesite was not working, with "commented" the line in the php.ini, now phpinfo shows "no value", re-booted the server and then after making the SSO with simplesaml, the $_SESSION variable is no more deleted.